# Существует ли в Django тип поля модели который хранит два целочисленных значения?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-model

Требуется создать такую модель, в которой будут поля которые хранят по два значения сразу(координаты в пикселях на документе).
Типа такого:
поле_координата = (15, 20).
Подскажите пожалуйста, существует ли в джанге некий тип полей такой?

Comment: Если тебя интересует именно координатная модель, то есть https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield, но там поле Point может принимать еще координату Z и не уверен, что значения обязательно должны быть целочисленными

Comment: Главное чтобы значение было двойное, т.е. одно поле модели содержало в себе два значения. Чтобы не плодить поля для х и y отдельно. GeoDjango гляну, спасибо.

Comment: GeoDjango хорош для географических координат, но там не целочисленные значения. С postgresql можно использовать ArrayField с интовыми элементами

Comment: Буду использовать ArrayField, проверил - больше подходит, спасибо.